# How to Embed a Custom Font Within a PDF Export of a ReportViewer Class

Tags: c#, pdf, fonts, reportviewer

I have a report I need to generate that requires a custom font.  I installed the custom font on the server from a .ttf file.  Here's the simplified C# code I use to export the report:

```
ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("SSRS\\Check.rdl");
viewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Local;
byte[] bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);
```

When I run this code, the custom font is not rendered in the PDF that is exported.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Somehow, it is working now.  I did not do anything that I know of.  Weird.

Comment: I tried both.  Still don't know what it was I did that got it to work.